# How to convert a Lucene.NET RangeQuery to a NumericRangeQuery for date range search?

Tags: c#, .net, lucene, lucene.net

I've implemented a Lucene.NET (2.9) search for events that has a query parameter that allows me to pass in a month and a year - it then returns all events that are running within that month (ie. if I pass in December 2013 it will match any events that run on a day within December). Each event has a StartDate and an EndDate parameter.

I've managed to get this working using a RangeQuery with code something like this:

```
Lucene.Net.Search.BooleanQuery bq = new Lucene.Net.Search.BooleanQuery();

DateTime lowerBoundDate = new DateTime(search.Year.Value, search.Month.Value, 1).Date;
DateTime upperBoundDate = new DateTime(search.Year.Value, search.Month.Value, DateTime.DaysInMonth(search.Year.Value, search.Month.Value)).Date;

string lowerDate = DateTools.DateToString(lowerBoundDate, DateTools.Resolution.DAY);
string upperDate = DateTools.DateToString(upperBoundDate, DateTools.Resolution.DAY);

// lowerDate would be first day of month, upperDate would be last day of month

var lowerRange = new RangeQuery(null, new Term("StartDate", upperDate), true);
var upperRange = new RangeQuery(new Term("EndDate", lowerDate), null, true);

var query = new BooleanQuery();

query.Add(new BooleanClause(lowerRange, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST));
query.Add(new BooleanClause(upperRange, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST));

bq.Add(query, Lucene.Net.Search.BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
```

However, I know RangeQuery has been deprecated and it seems like `NumericRangeQuery` is the way to go (using `NewIntRange)`, but I'm not sure how I go about converting my existing code to work with it. I presume I convert the date to an integer and use that, but not sure how the min and max bounds work [since being a value type both min and max must have a value].

All my attempts seem to result in no items being returned. For instance, here's an example:

```
var lowerNumericRange = NumericRangeQuery.NewIntRange("StartDate", 0, Convert.ToInt32(upperDate), true, true);
var upperNumericRange = NumericRangeQuery.NewIntRange("EndDate", Convert.ToInt32(lowerDate), 0, true, true);
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to switch over to a numeric query.  You are generating String date representations correctly, just switch over to a [`TermRangeQuery`](http://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/dc/d5a/class_lucene_1_1_net_1_1_search_1_1_term_range_query.html).

```
var lowerRange = new TermRangeQuery("StartDate", null, upperDate, true, true);
var upperRange = new TermRangeQuery("EndDate", lowerDate, null, true, true);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the conclusion I came to, too!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are best using [ToOADate()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tooadate.aspx) but you would need to store in this format originally.  Also you need to convert that to an int to as it also contains time in the decimal part.

```
var lowerNumericRange = NumericRangeQuery.NewIntRange("StartDate", 0, Convert.ToInt32(upperDate.ToOADate()), true, true);
var upperNumericRange = NumericRangeQuery.NewIntRange("EndDate", Convert.ToInt32(lowerDate.ToOADate()), 0, true, true);
```

Comment: Thanks - I'll probably use the TermRangeQuery but this is useful to know anyway.